# In asp.net-mvc, How can I show a loading image while my other image is getting generated from Url.Action?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, image, url.action

I have the following code:

```
 <img src="<%= Url.Action("LocationMap") %>" id="overlay" />
```

and it takes a little while for this to generate (as i am generating an image on the fly).

How can i show a "Loading . ." image or message, while this is being retrieved because right now it shows a broken image link until the image is loaded then it looks good . .

Comment: When are you rendering the image?  If you are doing into within the action that returns the page, you can't.  The browser will wait until the server is done generating the response before returning it.  You CAN render the page and then do an ajax call back to the server after the fact and show the loading image then.

Comment: thanks Justin. . if you change that to an answer i will accept as i moved it to an ajax call . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [this](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/08/05/jquery-check-whether-image-is-loaded/) ?

It just says to add code similar to the following:

```
<script>
  $('img').load(function() {
      //Hide Loading Mask;
  });
</script>
```